# Select lowest date in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with date condition:

```
SELECT
    MIN(date(a.changedttm)) as date,
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take,
    c.plan_start,
    c.plan_end 
FROM
    sctrail a,
    working_scene b,
    working_episode c,
    working_project d,
    master_scene e,
    master_project f,
    ref_themes g, 
    master_episode h,
    ref_status j
WHERE
    a.fkwsid = b.wsid
    AND b.fkweid=c.weid
    AND c.fkeid=h.eid
    AND c.fkwpid=d.wpid
    AND b.fksid = e.sid
    AND d.fkpid = f.pid
    AND d.fkrftid = g.rftid
    AND b.status=j.rsid
    AND date(a.changedttm) >= '$start_month'
    AND date(a.changedttm) <= '$end_month'
    AND a.appliedstatus != '0'
GROUP BY
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take
ORDER BY
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take;
```

It works fine except one thing, `MIN(date(a.changedttm))` is selected within the given range of dates.

So If I search from `2019-10-01` to `2019-10-31` it will select lowest date for this range only but I want to find lowest date for whole time.

Is there a way to change query to select `MIN(date(a.changedttm))` from whole table but keep date range inside WHERE?

Comment: To do this, you'll need to JOIN a separate select statement to get that lowest date value in the same resultset. Something like LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS ref, MIN(date) as minDate FROM ..) as _minDate ON _minDate.ref = main.ref

Comment: If your `WHERE` clause restricts to a certain range, then the only available lowest date is the starting point of that range.  Some sample data would really help here.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `WHERE` date range restriction to the `ON` condition of the first join from 
te `sctrail` table, and also make that first join a *left* join.  This should prevent any records in `sctrail` from being filtered off as a result of that join.

```
SELECT
    MIN(DATE(a.changedttm)) AS date,
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take,
    c.plan_start,
    c.plan_end 
FROM sctrail a
LEFT JOIN working_scene b
    ON a.fkwsid = b.wsid AND
       DATE(a.changedttm) BETWEEN '$start_month' AND '$end_month'
INNER JOIN working_episode c
    ON b.fkweid = c.weid
INNER JOIN working_project d
    ON c.fkwpid = d.wpid
INNER JOIN master_scene e
    ON b.fksid = e.sid
INNER JOIN master_project f
    ON d.fkpid = f.pid
INNER JOIN ref_themes g
    ON d.fkrftid = g.rftid
INNER JOIN master_episode h
    ON c.fkeid = h.eid
INNER JOIN ref_status j
    ON b.status = j.rsid
WHERE
    a.appliedstatus != '0'
GROUP BY
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take,
    c.plan_start,
    c.plan_end
ORDER BY
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take;
```

I replaced your implicit old school joins with modern explicit joins, which is the preferred way to write SQL now (and has been, for more than 25 years).  Also, I included a few more columns in the `GROUP BY` clause to make your query valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query, you can add column that contains a `subquery` of your `mindate()`

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MIN(date(changedttm)) FROM sctrail) as date,
    f.pcode,
    g.theme_name,
    h.ecode,
    c.take,
    c.plan_start,
    c.plan_end
FROM sctrail a,
INNER JOIN working_scene b ON a.fkwsid = b.wsid
INNER JOIN working_episode c ON b.fkweid = c.weid,
INNER JOIN working_project d ON c.fkeid = h.eid
INNER JOIN master_scene e ON c.fkwpid = d.wpid
INNER JOIN master_project f ON b.fksid = e.sid
INNER JOIN ref_themes g ON d.fkpid = f.pid
INNER JOIN master_episode h ON d.fkrftid = g.rftid
INNER JOIN ref_status j ON b.status = j.rsid
WHERE date(a.changedttm) >= '$start_month'
    AND date(a.changedttm) <= '$end_month'
    AND a.appliedstatus != '0'
ORDER BY f.pcode, g.theme_name, h.ecode, c.take;
```

Comment: I somehow suspect that the OP wants the minimum `changedttm` date within the scope of the query, but excluding the `WHERE` range restriction.  It will be interesting to see which one of us is right ^ ^